# When is the computation of casting executed?

Tags: c

I never really understood when happens what when it comes to casting.
I assume that implicit casting happens at compile time (correct me if I'm wrong), but what about this:

```
int i = 0;

double d = sqrt((double)i);
```

Will this happen at compile time/run time?

Comment: An optimizing compiler should do it at compile time because it can see the value of `i`. Runtime otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on optimization and architecture. For example, GCC with `-O3` will omit the call to `sqrt` altogether for some values, as seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ot9yzE).

If the variable is not known at compile-time (i.e. if it is read from a file or from user input), then there's no way around actually calling `sqrt` with the double value of `i`. On x86 this requires an instruction like [`CVTSI2SD`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtsi2sd) (Convert Doubleword Integer to Scalar Double-Precision Floating-Point Value), as seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Zy-Nfn). The compiler produces that instruction at compile time, but running the instruction (obviously) occurs at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

It does not matter, and it is not specified (check the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)). Be aware of the [as-if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule) rule. It actually depends on how your compiler is [optimizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).

If you put your code in just some `main` function and compile that with optimizations enabled, the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler could give you an empty program (since all the computations can be done at compile time, and since `d` is not used for observable side-effects).

If you have GCC, compile a function with your code using `gcc -O3 -S -fverbose-asm` and look inside the produced `*.s` assembler file. You'll be surprised.

Specifically, with GCC 8 on Linux/Debian/x86-64, the compilation of

```
// file dvep.c
#include <math.h>
int
main (void)
{
  int i = 0;
  double d = sqrt ((double) i);
  return 0;
}
```

using the `gcc -O3 -S -fverbose-asm dvep.c` command produces a `dvep.s` file whose `main` function is reduced to:

```
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
# dvep.c:9: }
    xorl    %eax, %eax  #
    ret 
    .cfi_endproc
```

and you then see that no floating point operations happens at runtime inside `main`